# How do I mount a Windows Live SkyDrive account as a partition?

Tags: software-recommendation, mount

Is there any software or steps to mount [Windows live Skydrive](http://skydrive.live.com/) so that we can upload files easily.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Gnome 3.6+ supports SkyDrive via [gnome-online-accounts](https://live.gnome.org/action/show/GnomeOnlineAccounts?action=show&redirect=OnlineAccounts). 3.4 and older only support chat iirc.

[`Source`](http://debarshiray.wordpress.com/2012/05/31/gnome-documents-skydrive/)

Comment: Thanks for citing a source. People really ought to do that more often :)

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be possible if you don't mind getting your hands dirty, according to [this blog post](http://www.brighthub.com/hubfolio/matthew-casperson/blog/archive/2010/09/01/syncing-files-to-skydrive-in-linux.aspx). I haven't tried it myself, though, but comments seem to indicate that it works, although with some limitations.

Comment: thanks, its not working for me, always 'Argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: requestUri' error

Comment: @Riyaz Here is the relevant [bug report](http://skydrivesync.codeplex.com/workitem/7676).

Answer (score 2):

I can use [SME](http://www.smestorage.com/) utility for this. [Here](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2011/12/mount-map-microsoft-skydrive-in-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot/) is described detailed solution.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Imagine the linked site goes down for maintenance or forever - your answer would become worthless.

Comment: I found SME a good solution, but it has one serious limitation. Its free account is limited to traffic of 1G per month.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy using [SME Storage](http://storagemadeeasy.com/)!

1. Download the the [SME app](http://smestorage.com/?p=static&page=LinuxDrive) that is relevant to your system
2. Extract and then search extracted files for a Debian package (*.deb)
3. Install the package
4. Register for an account with [SMEStorage](http://storagemadeeasy.com/)
5. Search your dash for "SMEStorage Explorer"
6. Sign in to your SMEStorage account
7. Select the icon with two circular prisms
8. Add SkyDrive as a source
9. Close program and search for "SMEStorage Client" in the dash
10. Enter the location you wish to mount your Online Storage
11. Click Mount

Good luck with your endeavour!

I originally did this with [LiberianGeek's Howto](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2011/12/mount-map-microsoft-skydrive-in-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot/), it worked well in Ubuntu 12.04 for me.

Comment: Can you use the information available on the website to build a nice answer for this post?

Comment: is that a good post?

Answer (score 0):

I personally didn't enjoy SMEStorage that much.

I'm quite happy with [Otixo](http://otixo.com/) as you can connect many different services to it and access all of them simply and smoothly mounting *dev.otixo.com* as Secure WebDAV (with your credential) in Nautilus. No extra software needed.