# mounting skydrive as a folder

Tags: mount, microsoft

Just finished up installing Ubuntu 12.10. I mainly need a system for school(grad school) so theres a few things I would really like to do, especially Skydrive.

Does anyone know how to mount Skydrive as a folder? I know there is a website SMEStorage.com but I do not wish to go through a third party and even then they have bandwith limits.

I will be installing a latex distribution but before I can do that I need access to my 2 gigs of data in skydrive.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I mount a Windows Live SkyDrive account as a partition?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/23230/how-do-i-mount-a-windows-live-skydrive-account-as-a-partition)

Comment: Try This [Ubuntu One](https://one.ubuntu.com/)

Answer (score 1):

The following link has instructions on how to go about doing this:

[Installing SkyDrive (SMEStorage) on Ubuntu 12.04](http://www.rubynginx.com/index.php/2012/09/27/installing-skydrive/)

It makes use of SME (Storage Made Easy), which provides a deb file for Ubuntu. Supports 12.10 and 13.04.

Answer (score 1):

There is several disadvantage of SME. First, it is not free, there is huge limitation especially in the monthly bandwidth you can spend on syncs. Also you can add maximum of 3 providers in the free version. Of course you can pay $60 for the lifetime account, but unfortunately it is still not the perfect solution.

SME is not a real sync app, it is simply connects to your other accounts on-demand, so it is not like dropbox where you can access your files when you are offline...